# FILE write ; SSH_AGENT_PID=2547?

Tags: c, file

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to work out some examples on file operations.
When I write on a file using my code I'm getting some extra text following what I've written.

```
SSH_AGENT_PID=2547
```

Please tell me what this means and how could I avoid this?
Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int i;
        FILE *fp;

        fp = fopen(argv[1], "w");
        for(i = 0; i < argc; i ++)
        {
                fprintf(fp, argv[i + 2]);
                fprintf(fp, " ");
        }
        fclose(fp);

        return 0;
}
```

This is what i can see in my command line

```
[root@localhost basicC]# cc file_create_write.c
[root@localhost basicC]# ./a.out /root/kernel_programming/basicC/test_file.txt ajish alfred in focuz infotech
[root@localhost basicC]# cat test_file.txt
ajish alfred in focuz infotech  SSH_AGENT_PID=2547 [root@localhost basicC]#
```

Answer (score 2):

Some systems actually have a [three argument `main`](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Program-Arguments.html) where the third argument holds the environment variables. You are running off the end of `argv` (as Igor Oks notes) and getting into the environment variable list; if you look at your environment variables, you should see `SSH_AGENT_PID` with a value of 2547 (or some other number).

Your loop should look more like this:

```
for(i = 2; i < argc; i++)
    fprintf(fp, "%s ", argv[i]);
```

You don't care about `argv[0]` and you've already used `argv[1]` for the filename so you want to start at `argv[2]` not add 2 to `i`.

I also changed your `fprintf` call to use an explicit format string. If you don't do that, whatever is in `argv[i]` will be interpreted as a format string and you'll get strange things happening if `argv[i]` contains a percent sign.

Furthermore, it looks like you're learning C programming while logged in as root. That's a bad idea. A very very bad idea. An even worse idea that doing normal tasks while logged in as root. You should login as a normal user so you don't accidentally erase `/dev` or something.

Answer (score 0):

`argc` contains the number of arguments passed to the program. When you access `argv[argc]` and `argv[argc+1]`, you are actually accessing out-of-bounds memory locations.

You can do

```
for(i = 2; i < argc; i++)
{
    fprintf(fp, argv[i]);
```

instead of

```
for(i = 0; i < argc; i++)
{
    fprintf(fp, argv[i + 2]);
```